# FluentValidation: Only do .Must when field is not empty

Tags: fluentvalidation

I would like to only check for a `.Must` condition when a field is not empty/null.

The following code is not evaluation `.Must` properly (`.CheckUrl` not being called) when bad urls are passed.

```
RuleFor(c => c.Website)
            .Must((item, list, context) => ValidationHelper.CheckUrl(item.Website, context))
            .When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Website));
```

I want to fail the validation only if something is passed for url, empty should not fail it.

I could change the .`CheckUrl` method to return true if url empty and remove the `.When` but i prefer not to do that if there is a way around the validation rules itself

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with your code. What makes you think, your rule is not working as expected?

Comment: You may use 'Unless' in order to avoid negating the Boolean